# Package Update error

Tags: updates, package-management

I can't seem to get any updates installed. I keep getting the following errors. How do I solve this?

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-44
  linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.52.62.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.52.62.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `apt-get -f install linux-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided us with output but have not told us exactly what *you* are doing that produces it, so any answer to this question will probably be speculative in nature. However, feel free to edit your question to provide more information.

One common cause of this sort of problem is if you are attempting to upgrade or install software from the Terminal with `apt-get` or `aptitude`, without first running `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo aptitude update`).

So, if you're running `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, or `install` commands from the Terminal without first running an `update` command, then you should do that.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The error message is saying that a package cannot be installed because it depends on an *older* version of a package than is available. Running `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo aptitude update`) updates information on your computer about what packages are available in what versions from where, and what packages/versions they depend on.